# Раскладка клавиатуры windows 11 меняется дважды при нажатии shift+alt

Tags: windows, клавиатура, layout

Пол года назад я совершил ужасную ошибку - поставил 11 винду.
Помимо очевидных проблем типа невозможности драгнуть файл в окно приложения, наведя на его иконку в таскбаре, или частых вылетов процесса рабочего стола, больше всего мне не даёт покоя эта проблема.

Какое то время назад, раскладка клавиатуры периодически перестала меняться. Формально, она меняется, но после этого моментально возвращается обратно. Это ужасно мешает, поверьте. Теперь я заметил, что это происходит, если сначала нажать alt, а потом shift, с небольшой задержкой. Это появилось не сразу, а только около пары месяцев назад, видимо с каким-то обновлением. У меня нет идей, что с этим можно сделать. В гугле ничего подобного не нашёл.

### [Вот как это выглядит](https://vk.com/video402150900_456240355)

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Попробуйте на Ctrl+shift перейти и попробовать. Нажимать на порядок легче ( мизинцем одним) и проблем меньше

Comment: @KoVadim не соглашусь, у меня руки сами по себе давно уже на wasd лежат, и 2 пальца быстрее делают, чем запястье двигать

Comment: Я не предлагаю на постоянно. Просто попробовать. Сам я давно перешёл на capslock и мне очень нравится